# MySQL slow query log file time elapse

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, performance, slow-log

Does anybody know when the mysql slow log file delete slow query records?

based on my daily observation. The log file starts at 7am. I have searched for this but nothing answers me clearly. My server version if 5.6.14. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably done by your log rotation software. On my Ubuntu machine its defined in `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server`.

`logrotate` is run daily by a cron job. Take a look in `/etc/crontab`. In my case I have the following:

`25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )`

So daily jobs get run at 6:25AM.

I also have a file `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` which configures log rotate as a daily job.

Most Linux installations would have something similar. If you're running on Windows I'm afraid I have no idea.

Comment: Hi Mr. Colin, Thank you very much for this. I found a separate logrotate where the slowlogs are saved in a directory. Thank you for the idea for logrotate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Never.  It just grows and grows.  All the more reason to fix the slow queries.

(Or you could do something to delete the file.  Of course it will come back.)